# managing api keys in gitlab project

Tags: gitlab

I have a gitlab project that is mirroring (pull) a github private repo. Because of its origins, the repo has a "config/private.js" file with all the api keys and server config that it needs. Or rather, that file isnt in the repo, its in *.gitignore*.

How do I populate my gitlab environment with this file? It would be ideal if I could reserve a special file that is not in the repo and does not update with commits, and is used to populate the dist environment with a build command like:

```
- cat secrets.file > src/config/private.js
```

But -- I'm having no luck finding that in the documentation. I do se project and group secrets -- but 1. that would be tedious just to add them and 2. I would need to rewrite the code, or else create another just as tedious script to echo each to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a tad complicated.

Gitlab does not install the repo it installs the build results, thus you can inject api key files in gitlab's CI CD - but you would have to change it/rebuild for each env. (You couldnt test results and then redeploy known working results to prod.) In my case, I was building once, and committed to only applying relevant keys to stage and prod.

What I do is I keep the secrets as variables on the destination. I inject a key file that refers to the env during CI CD. For example, it might set a key to `__MY_API_KEY__`. I use a postinstall script in deployment to apply these env keys to the built scripts that are installed (this is just a tr command over a set of env variables and /build files).

This way, I can use a hard coded, *gitignored* private file locally, and still inject private keys specific to each env separately.